# Constituency vs Dependency Parsing: What is more effective for Sentiment Analysis?

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis, parsing

Parsing is often used to understand the sentiment of complex sentences filled with double negations or very articulated.

There are two main ways of parsing a sentence: **Constituency** and **Dependency Parsing**. What is the most successful application for Sentiment Analysis?

Answer (score 2):

Both approaches have been used for sentiment analysis in the literature. From a quick search, we can find these results:

- Constituency parsing:

  - [Deep Recursive Neural Networks for Compositionality in Language](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5551-deep-recursive-neural-networks-for-compositionality-in-language) [NeurIPS'14]
  - [Less Grammar, More Features](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P14-1022/)[ACL'14]
  - [A Statistical Parsing Framework for Sentiment Classification](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/J15-2004/) [Computational Linguistics journal'15]
- Dependency parsing:

  - [What's great and what's not: learning to classify the scope of negation for improved sentiment analysis](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W10-3110/) [NeSp-NLP'10]
  - [UBham: Lexical Resources and Dependency Parsing for Aspect-Based Sentiment Analysis](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/S14-2122) [SemEval'14]

It seems to me that constituency parsing has been used more than dependency parsing. My sample, however, is very small and focused on the English language. I think this may change in languages with more complex (and more [non-projective](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/3640/27030)) syntax.

That been said, I think currently neither of them are considered to be state of the art in sentiment analysis. If we take a look at the leaderboards of sentiment analysis tasks from [paperswithcode](https://paperswithcode.com/task/sentiment-analysis), all of the leading approaches (BERT, RoBERTa, M5) handle text as a mere sequence of tokens. While these results are from only a

Comment: Yeah, BERT and all the Transformer-based family is SOTA, and parsing is no longer hot. I just need a parsing model to make some "NLP experiments" with the syntactic structures. Something that, as you explained, is not done by Transformers.